# A case of general function transformation in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm (trying to) learning about mutable state in Haskell. To keep things simple, I define

```
data Car = Car { position :: Int }
```

and

```
move :: Car -> Int -> Car
move c n =  Car { position = n + (position c) }
```

Thus, `move` is a "pure" function that represents a transition of a Car into another one.

I think that I'll need to hold a Car in a mutable variable so I can have the current position (after some movements are made to the car).
Therefore I define (I hope this is the way to go, otherwise correct me) the following

```
type Parking = IORef Car -- holds a car

newParking :: Car -> IO Parking
newParking = newIORef
```

as well as trivial `getCar :: Parking -> IO Car` and `setCar :: Parking -> Car -> IO ()` functions.

The above code seems to be fine.

**The question:**

Could I define a function that transform *any* pure function like `move :: Car -> Int -> Car` into a function `Parking -> Int -> ()` that applies `move` to the parked Car and replaces it with the new one?

**The example after incorporating the accepted answer**

```
import Data.IORef
import Control.Concurrent

-- -----------------------------------------------------

timeGoesBy place = do
        moveTheCar place
        threadDelay 1000000
        timeGoesBy place

moveTheCar place = do
     car <- getCar place
     print $ getPos car
     modifyCar place (move 7)    

-- -----------------------------------------------------
main = do
     place <- newParking (newCar 1000)
     timeGoesBy place
     print "end"

-- -----------------------------------------------------

type Parking = IORef Car -- mutable var for holding a car (the car may be replaced)

newParking :: Car -> IO Parking
newParking = newIORef 

getCar :: Parking -> IO Car
getCar = readIORef 

setCar :: Parking -> Car -> IO ()
setCar = writeIORef

modifyCar :: Parking -> (Car -> Car) -> IO ()
modifyCar = modifyIORef

-- -----------------------------------------------------

data Car = Car { position :: Int } -- Car data type ("pure")

-- create a car
newCar :: Int -> Car
newCar v = Car { position = v}

-- get the position of a car
getPos :: Car -> Int
getPos c = (position c)

-- move : transform a given car into a new "moved car"
move :: Int -> Car -> Car -- first the int so that we can curry (i.e. move 7)
move n car = Car { position = n + (position car) }
```

Comment: Would you be happy with `Int -> Car -> Car` and `T1 -> T2 -> Tn -> Car -> Car` instead? That makes it much simpler.

Comment: Wouldn't the State Monad be a better alternative? Unless the goal is to learn about IORef.

Comment: @Attic I don't really know :-( Maybe, could you give a hint on how to do it with the State Monad. (By the moment, I fear monads).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can.

For example:

```
doCarStuff :: Parking -> (Car -> Car) -> IO ()
doCarStuff = modifyIORef
```

If you rearrange your `move` function so that the `Car` argument comes last, then you can do

```
doCarStuff myParking (move 5)
```

which does what you want.

Comment: Seems great and simple !

Comment: `Car` comes last is always a win, even for `T1 -> T2 -> Tn -> Car -> Car` since you can use partial application.

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, we could use the State Monad to avoid /actual/ mutability.

```
import Control.Monad.State
```

Define the Car stucture

```
data Car = Car { position :: Int } deriving Show
```

initiate the state, we use execState, give it a function that will hold the state and the initial state (Car 0).

```
start :: Car
start = execState myState (Car 0)
```

move will move your car

```
move :: Int -> Car -> Car
move n c = c { position = n + position c }
```

doStuff will help up make it easier to apply functions to the State Monad 'get' gets us the current state (Car 0) and 'put' puts the a new version into the state. We first get it, apply f on it, and then put it in the new state.

```
doStuff :: MonadState a m => (a -> a) -> m ()
doStuff f = get >>= put . f
```

This is the State function, here we simply call doStuff with move 1 and it'll modify our car (Car 0) to move 1 Int, so the new result will be Car 1. then we say move 3 and it'll change to Car 4

```
myState :: State Car ()
myState = do
    doStuff $ move 1
    doStuff $ move 3
```

With this we can run the start function and receive our modified initial (Car 0).

Answer (score 3):

Here's one more possibility, using the *lens* library to automatically derive "getters" and "setters" for your objects. First there's a little bit of boilerplate

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.State

newtype Car = Car { _position :: Int } deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Car
```

Now you can write routines that look and feel 'imperative', for example

```
program = do
  p <- use position
  liftIO . putStrLn $ "Initial position is: " ++ show p
  position += 3
  q <- use position
  liftIO . putStrLn $ "  Final position is: " ++ show q

main = evalStateT program (Car 0)
```

which results in

```
>> main
Initial position is: 0
  Final position is: 3
```

If you want to use a generic function to modify the fields of a record, you can use `over`, as in

```
>> let square x = x * x
>> over position square (Car 4)
Car {_position = 16}
```

and if you want that to have the same "imperative" feel you had before

```
action = do
  position %= square
  p <- use position
  liftIO . putStrLn $ "New position: " ++ show p
```

and

```
>> evalStateT action (Car 4)
New position: 16
```